# How to use Renderer2 to make parentNode and emulating a click safer?

Tags: angular

Renderer2 is safer than ElementRef, I've changed to Renderer2 based on this [article](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/renderer2-angular). There are a few below I don't know how to make them safer:

**parentNode**
HTML

```
<ul><li *ngFor="let t of ThumbnailsOfImages"><img src="{{c}}" (click)="useThisThumbnail($event);"/></li></ul>
```

TS

```
useThisThumbnail(i: any)
{
  i.target.style="...";
  this.indexOfThumbnail = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(i.target.parentNode.parentNode.childnodes, i.target.parentNode);
}
```

**emulating a click** HTML

```
<button (click)="addFiles()">Add Files</button>
```

TS

```
addFiles() { this.file.nativeElement.click(); }
```

Comment: Do you want this code conversation into renderer2

Comment: @GaurangDhorda Sorry, don't understand you well. I'm wondering if they need to be converted using `Renderer2`, and if so how.